# Check if socket is listening in C

Tags: c, sockets, file-descriptor

While iterating through socket file descriptors, how can I check if one of them is from a passive socket (listening for connections)?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This can be checked with [getsockopt](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getsockopt.html)([SO_ACCEPTCONN](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_10_16)).  For example:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>

int val;
socklen_t len = sizeof(val);
if (getsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ACCEPTCONN, &val, &len) == -1)
    printf("fd %d is not a socket\n", fd);
else if (val)
    printf("fd %d is a listening socket\n", fd);
else
    printf("fd %d is a non-listening socket\n", fd);
```

Comment: FWIW: Mac OS X High Sierra (10.13.6) does not seem to accept SO_ACCEPTCONN. The man page for getsockopt does not have it; and a call gets you back error 42: Protocol not available.

Answer (score 0):

You can run in the command line (on a Mac/Linux enviroment):

```
lsof -i
```

and/or (Linux/Mac/Windows enviroment)

```
netstat -a
```

Comment: He asked for a C solution (not I was the down).

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, you could try performing an operation on the socket which would incidentally determine what type of socket it is, like trying to accept a connection from it. If `accept()` fails with EINVAL, that's a pretty good sign that it isn't listening. :)

Keeping track of which sockets are which is a better solution overall, though. Unless you're building a really trivial application, chances are that you'll need to keep some sort of additional data on each socket anyway.